# XNA Content Pipeline Tutorial

Tags: c#, xna

I want to use the content pipeline for building objects in my level, and I tried to use the microsoft tutorial for writing a content importer and all the rest, but IIRC it didnt work. Anyone know where a decent tutorial or two is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one over at Ziggyware and another at [XNAWiki](http://www.xnawiki.com/index.php/XNA_Content_Pipeline_using_VB.NET).  Have Fun.

Comment: The ziggyware url is broken now.

Comment: Most content on the XNAWiki seems to have been replaced by commercials.

Answer (score 3):

I don't program in XNA, but would this help?

http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnhar/archive/2008/11/24/content-pipeline-assemblies.aspx

And a collection of links about the XNA Content Pipeline:

http://blogs.msdn.com/etayrien/archive/2008/02/15/useful-content-pipeline-links.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There's one on [RB Whitaker's Wiki](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/content-pipeline-extension-1) which is very succinct.  I liked it.